# What is the difference between OnlineLDA and EMLDA in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib, lda

We are working on a project where we need to run LDA on topic identification , so we have applied the OnlineLDA for this , but for that we are getting the OOM exception, when we try to increase the iteration.

Hence we tried to shift to EMLDA if it scales better!

So my question is which one is better in terms of performance , memory management etc?

**Corpus Size :** 86k+ Documents

**Topics Number :** 2000+

**P.S:** On a side note we need to apply the LDA on the Stream data in future , I see a spark Ticket for it but it seems its still on hold , so if someone can suggest me a way around that would work like a charm . Thanks !

Comment: **Online variational inference** is a technique for learning an LDA model by processing the data incrementally in small batches. By processing in small batches, the Online implementation scales better than **EM** . [Here](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/22/large-scale-topic-modeling-improvements-to-lda-on-apache-spark.html) you can see a performance comparison between Online and EM. How many iteration did you tried? and can you describe your hardware environment?

Comment: we have 10 iteration, 50 topics, worker with 24GB RAM each its amazon server